# git clone silent doesn't work

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I am trying to clone a repo automatically from a `.bat` file.

I use ssh so the .bat file first moves a "`id_rsa`" file to the "`user\.ssh`" folder.

Then, when I run "`git clone ssh://repo c:\repo`", I get the question

```
The authenticity of host can't be established. 
RSA key fingerprint is ........ 
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

If I answer yes manually it works and the "`known_hosts`" file is created in "`user\.ssh`" folder. Now if I run the `.bat` file the `git clone` will work without the question.

I need to do this silently from the `.bat` file.
I have tried to answer `yes` from the `.bat` file and to add "`> /dev/nul 2>&1`" but with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should try and adapt "[Can I automatically add a new host to known_hosts?](https://serverfault.com/a/366751/783)" in order to add the remote server to your `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\known_hosts`.

Even from your Windows bat script, you can use a /path/to/git/bin/bash -c '...' command.

```
c:\path\to\git\bin\bash -c 'ssh-keyscan -t rsa,dsa HOST 2>&1 | sort -u - ~/.ssh/known_hosts > ~/.ssh/tmp_hosts && mv ~/.ssh/tmp_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
```

That allows you to use linux commands like grep, sort, ... which are part of the git distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an updated bash?. Essentially what you're doing here is redirect to /dev/null, which is "nowhere". If you want to do it silently you can try git clone git@gitlab.com:username/repo directory -q

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, at least for now, I download both the known_hosts file and id_rsa from another server.